# How to get data back from QVariant for a usertype?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using a `QVariant` to store a pointer to my object in a `QComboBox`

```
void MainFrame::initContainerBox(QComboBox *oBox)
{
    IDataContainer *idc = new CSVContainer();
    QVariant v(QVariant::UserType, idc);

    oBox->addItem(idc->getContainername(), v);
    void *idc1 = v.data();
    if(idc1 == idc)
        printf("Test\n");
}
```

But how do I get the data back? When I use `data()` the pointer is different, so this doesn't seem to be correct. From gooogling I had the impression that I have to register a type for each class I want to use in a `QVariant` is that correct or can I retrieve the value without that?

Comment: Use `QVariant::value()`

Comment: I have been using `value` as well, but it doesn't work. Can you give a working example?

Comment: @Devolus: out of curiosity, what did not work? Have you tried the example [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html#value)?

Comment: @LaszloPapp, I was trying to find a fully selfcontained example. When I tried to implement it, I either found partial examples, or examples with supported types. That's why I posted as an answer a fully compilable example which shows all steps in a single posts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After two days of googling and trying all kind of combinations I finally found out how to do this. Here is an example using a `QComboBox` putting an item and getting it back. `IDataContainer *` is an arbitrary class which is not related to Qt.

```
Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(IDataContainer *)

void MainFrame::initContainerBox(QComboBox *oBox)
{
    IDataContainer *idc = new CSVContainer();
    QVariant v;
    v.setValue(idc);

    oBox->addItem(idc->getContainername(), v);
    QVariant v2 = oBox->itemData(oBox->currentIndex());

    IDataContainer *idc1 = v2.value<IDataContainer *>();
    if(idc1 == idc)
        printf("Test\n");
}
```

So with my first approach of using `value()` I was on the right track, the only missing bits were how to set the value and using the macro `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(IDataContainer *)`.

Apparently using the constructor doesn't work, so one has to call `setValue()` instead. If somebody knows how to use the constructor it would be nice to show it.

Comment: Try `QVariant v(QVariant::fromValue(idc));`. Although I don't know, if that's prettier :)

Comment: Thanks (+1) for sharing the answer. I wish more would do this. That really helped me.